# Using pointers to get to data in structs in classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct, constructor

I am trying to write a program that will solve a maze using a class and a tree.  I am trying to use a class to represent the maze (the design will be entered using cin), and the class contains a struct as a private member.

This struct contains two ints (for the x and y coordinate of the position) and an array with 3 spaces that will hold three pointers to other structs.

In the constructor function for my class, I am trying to set all the pointers in the array to NULL to start off.  The program compiles fine, but when I get to the constructor the program gives me a segmentation fault.  Here is some relevant code:

```
const int POSSIBLE_BRANCHES = 3; //at any point the path can split in 3 ways

struct PathNode
{
    int x_coord;
    int y_coord;
    PathList branches[POSSIBLE_BRANCHES];
};
typedef PathNode *PathList;

class Maze
{
    private:
        PathList initial_pos;
    public:
        Maze();
};
```

And the constructor:

```
Maze::Maze()
{
     cout << "entered constructor" << endl;
     for (int i = 0; i < POSSIBLE_BRANCHES; i++)
     {
          initial_pos->branches[i] = NULL;
     }

}
```

I get the "entered constructor" phrase printed out, but the program stops immediately afterwards.  I am assuming it is some silly problem with my pointer syntax, but I have been unable to locate the problem.

As I understand it: the -> operator dereferences the pointer to the PathNode struct, so now we have access to the members like x_coord, y_coord, and branches.  The [] operator gets to each index of the branches array.  And because it is an array of pointers to PathNodes, setting them as NULL should be fine.  Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Edit: 
Solved.  See the answer marked as best.

Comment: You never allocate `initial_pos` with new

Comment: Why use a pointer anyway?

Comment: Why not use use a `PathNode` for the initial pos  and call it good?

Comment: You should do the allocating in the MIL (Member Initialization List).

Comment: You are buying yourself a lot of future pain by using that pointer. Are you absolutely sure you need it? Some time soon you will be asking why your code is leaking memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't yet allocated initial_pos before you use it. That is causing the segfault.
Something along the lines of:

```
Maze::Maze()
    : initial_pos(new PathNode)
{
     cout << "entered constructor" << endl;
     for (int i = 0; i < POSSIBLE_BRANCHES; i++)
     {
          initial_pos->branches[i] = NULL;
     }
}
```

Should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be running just fine.  Although I am unfamiliar with the syntax you used with the single semicolon.  What effect does that have?

Comment: The semicolon after the constructor name tells the compiler "I'm about to initialize member variables". 

If you have multiple variables, comma separate them. This syntax is commonly referred to as the MIL.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I haven't learned about that yet.  I appreciate the clear answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza be nice, clearly a beginner. Pointing them to std::unique_ptr and std::vector before they understand working with raw pointers would be rude and uncalled for.

Comment: That was for you :-) You have just given them a memory leak. You should at least warn them how to use dynamic allocation safely.

Comment: @juanchopanza nah... no point in explaining deallocation yet. They clearly don't understand how pointers work yet. Baby steps.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is the first thing that gets called for the new class, so you never allocate or initialize `initial_pos` in anyway, but you then dereference it - leading to undefined behavior (most likely causing a segfault)